SQL - Merge results for the same object in one row
I want to achieve the following:
Table 1: Country



CountryID
Name




1
USA


2
France



Table 2:



CityID
Name




1
New York


2
Boston


3
Paris


4
Lyon



Table 3: MapCity



MapID
CountryID
CityID




1
1
1


2
1
2


3
2
3


4
2
4



Desired Result:



Country.Name
Cities




USA
New York, Boston


France
Paris, Lyon



Specifically, it is about how I combine the results in the Cities column.
With the following command I get all the data but one line per city, but I need one line per country and the cities should be merged there.
SELECT *
FROM Country
JOIN MapCity ON Country.CountryID=MapCity.CountyID
JOIN City ON MapCity.City=City.CityID


Try GROUP BY with GROUP_CONCAT
